# Backend changes stopped working in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to set the categories to view as 2 columns with left bar in display settings but Im still seeing the 3column template - also tried setting the category to show static block only but it's still showing products. Any ideas?

Comment: make sure that you apply change on right category and also clear cache after chages

Comment: Make sure you reindex the data after your changes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin->catalog->manage categories->choose desired category as you want to display 2 column with left bar.Now go custom design tab and change page layout with 2 column left bar.
For display Static block rather than product go to Display setting tab and change display mode to static block only.Now Assign CMS block as you want display.

You can also change Category Page Layout 
Go to app/design/frontend/package/theme/layout/local.xml
and put this script.Always refresh cache and indexing after these changes

```
> <layout>
>     <catalog_category_layered>
>       <reference name="root">
>         <action method="setTemplate">
>           <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
>         </action>
>       </reference>
>     </catalog_category_default>
>     <catalog_category_layered>
>       <reference name="root">
>         <action method="setTemplate">
>           <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template> 
>         </action>
>       </reference>
>     </catalog_category_default> </layout>
```